# Calculate average days between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, average

I have the following table:

| Team | PhoneNumber | OrderNo | CallDate | OrderDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TM1 | 2222222222 | 26699443 | 2021-01-28 | 2021-02-05 |
| TM1 | 1111111111 | 26699450 | 2021-01-22 | 2021-01-22 |
| TM2 | 5555555555 | 26699466 | 2021-02-22 | 2021-02-23 |
| TM2 | 5555555555 | 26699467 | 2021-01-22 | 2021-02-01 |
| TM3 | 7777777777 | 26699488 | 2020-12-10 | 2021-01-03 |

I want to calculate the average time from call to order for each team for each month. This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    Team,
    MONTH(CallDate),
    AVG(DATEDIFF(day,CallDate,OrderDate))
FROM MyTab AS C 
GROUP BY Team, MONTH(CallDate)
```

I want to calculate the difference between the CallDate and the OrderDate and
then apply the Average for each team for each month.

Comment: Also, there is no time portion in your `CallDate`, and `OrderDate` so calculating a "time" (in minutes, seconds?) seems pointless. At best you'll be able to get the average number of days.

Comment: @Larnu my bad I forgot to include the query

Comment: So what isn't working with your code? Please show your actual results and your expected results.

Comment: Please share your desired output.

Comment: @Larnu I want to calculate the difference between the CallDate and the OrderDate and then apply the Average for each team for each month.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no time part in the data so how you are planning to calculate time? Do you want to multiply number of days with 24 or 8 (official time)? Please mention. If orderdate and calldate are same date then day will be 0 or one? I have considered it as 1 day.

**To calculate day difference:**

```
SELECT 
    Team,
    format(CallDate,'yyyy-MMMM') Month,
    AVG(DATEDIFF(day,CallDate,OrderDate)+1) AverageDayTaken
FROM MyTab AS C 
GROUP BY Team, format(CallDate,'yyyy-MMMM')
```

**Output:**

[image]

**To calculate working hour difference(8 hour per day):**

```
SELECT 
    Team,
    format(CallDate,'yyyy-MMMM') Month,
    AVG(DATEDIFF(day,CallDate,OrderDate)+1)*8 AverageWorkingHourTaken
FROM MyTab AS C 
GROUP BY Team, format(CallDate,'yyyy-MMMM')
```

Comment: I updated my question : I want to calculate the difference between the CallDate and the OrderDate and then apply the Average for each team for each month.